# Encountered Error Could not load type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Internal.IWrapsElement' from assembly 'WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, chromedriver, selenium-webdriver-c#, edge-chromium

I'm working in multiple browser testing. It was working code with chrome browser. Recently I have installed "Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver -Version 4.0.0-alpha04".

MSedge Chromium and chrome working in setup method, But while navigate/return back to actual [Test]  test method encountered the below error.

> Error:Message: System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type
> 'OpenQA.Selenium.Internal.IWrapsElement' from assembly 'WebDriver,
> Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Is this dll/package confused

```c#
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
   string Browsername = "Chrome";
   switch (Browsername)
   {
      case "Chrome":
      driver = new ChromeDriver();
   }
}

[Test]
[Obsolete]
public void XXXX()
{
    try
    {
       driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(UrlList.XXXX_Login);
       driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200));
       driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
       Login login = new Login(driver);
       login.PerformLogin(Login.email_id1, Login.pswd1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to double check the usings  and recompile. `OpenQA.Selenium.Internal` should be `OpenQA.Selenium`. You are trying to call a moved interface.

> Per v4.0.0a1 in
> https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG
> "Moved IWrapsDriver and IWrapsElement from the
> OpenQA.Selenium.Internal namespace to the OpenQA.Selenium namespace.
> This should be a no-op for the vast majority of users, requiring only
> a recompile of code, given that both of these interfaces feature
> return types in the base namespace, meaning that users likely already
> have "using" statements for the root namespace in their source. If
> errors are encountered, changing the namespace in the code and
> rebuilding should resolve the error."
>
> <sub>Source: [IWrapsElement Error on Protractor 0.12.0 and Selenium.WebDriver 4.0.0-alpha01 #82](https://github.com/bbaia/protractor-net/issues/82)</sub>

Comment: I checked in my code, i haven't use the OpenQA.Selenium.Internal used only OpenQA.Selenium. I have removed the the namespace NUnit.Framework.Internal also.

Comment: Maybe another library is using it?

Comment: after uninstallation of "Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver -Version 4.0.0-alpha04" its working, shall i try alpha03 version?

Comment: Dont you have a stack-trace? There is some line of code that is triggering this, you want to know which one.

Comment: In pagefactory getting error, in call stack got the error message like ((OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver)driver).ApplicationCache = '((OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver)driver).ApplicationCache' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Comment: I couldn't find which line of code triggering the error

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error.

I had to uninstall (WebDriver -Version 4.0.0-alpha04) and reinstall the Selenium.Support and Selenium.WebDriver.

The problem is resolved with Selenium Support 3.141.0 and Selenium  WebDriver 3.141.0.

Answer (score 0):

Update the version of the Selenium Support package you are using to the same version number as the Selenium WebDriver package.

That is, if you've upgraded to Selenium WebDriver 4.0.0-rc2 and you're also using the Selenium Support package, then you need to upgrade the Selenium Support package version to 4.0.0-rc2.

Answer (score 0):

The same for me, The problem was resolved only after updating Selenium Support  and Selenium  WebDriver to 3.141.0.